# How to compute gradients of 1D-Convolution with respect to input in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient, backpropagation, conv1d

I need to compute gradients of 1D Convolution with respect to input in tensorflow. I know if this would have been 2D convolution, I could have used **tf.compat.v1.nn.conv2d_backprop_input**. I want to do this on 1D convolution. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

I know about normal gradients calculation but that is not the same. What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape). This should work for 1D data as well es for 2D images.